# What is the number of distinct quadruples $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ of non-negative integers, such that $x_i\ge i$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le18$?

Tags: combinatorics, inequality

I have an exercise on which I am struggling.

> What is the number of distinct quadruples $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ of non-negative integers, such that $x_i\ge i$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le18$?

I started to tackle this problem by tackling a less complicated similar problem:
the number of distinct quadruples $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ of non-negative integers such that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le18$.
This would be $\sum_{k=4}^{21}{k \choose 4}$ if I made no mistake. How would I then account for the additional condition?

Comment: Did you mean "distinct" quintuples?

Comment: quintuple or quadrupole ?

Comment: quadruple sorry I will edit the question right now !

Comment: they are in fact distinct sorry will edit the question too !

Comment: I believe the number of solutions to be 45 but I am not sure of this. I approached this problem by searching for all quadrupole that are solutions without worrying about the $x_i\ge i$. However I don't know how to go forward.

Comment: I get $\binom{18 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{22}{4}$ solutions for the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \leq 18$ in the nonnegative integers since it is equivalent to solving the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + s = 18$ in the nonnegative integers, where $s = 18 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  i \le x_i \quad \left| {\;1 \le i \le 4} \right. \hfill \cr 
  x_1  + x_2  + x_3  + x_4  \le 18 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le y_k \quad \left| {\;1 \le k \le 4} \right. \hfill \cr 
  y_1  + 1 + y_2  + 2 + y_3  + 3 + y_4  + 4 \le 18 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le y_k \left( { \le 8} \right)\quad \left| {\;1 \le k \le 4} \right. \hfill \cr 
  \left( {0 \le } \right)y_1  + y_2  + y_3  + y_4  \le 8 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Leftrightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Leftrightarrow \quad {\rm number}\;{\rm of}\;{\rm ways}\;{\rm to}\;{\rm distribute}\;{\rm up}\;{\rm to}\;{\rm 8}\;{\rm (undisting}{\rm .)}\;{\rm balls}  \cr 
  & {\rm into}\;{\rm 4}\;{\rm (disting}{\rm .)}\;{\rm bins} \cr} 
$$

Comment: Wow that's a really clever way of solving this ! Thank you so much. I am sorry if my post wasn't that clear by the way as it was my first ever !

Comment: that's just because I did similar exercises .. before you : glad to help !